# How do I erase all data on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I have had countless problems since I let one of my friends borrow my PC and I had forgotten to create a backup. Now I want to start a new but I'm missing an USB key to make a bootable one and it is kind of a pressing matter.

So how could i make my Ubuntu look like one that has never been touched before?

Comment: The only way to 'factory reset' an Ubuntu installation is, unfortunately, to do a reinstallation.  There's no other real way to get it back to the 'factory clean' settings, in a sense, to where it appears untouched.

Comment: Seems like i'll have to beg people around me for an old usb key :( but thank you for the information!

Answer (score -1):

Your options are really discussed here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

You could do network, you could repartition your disk and install to the new disk from your current installation, the mininal install is only 40Mb if you have something which could hold that much.